# how can get hard disk serial number using cmd

Tags: cmd, window, command, admin

I am use a command for finding hard disk serial number  "wmic diskdrive get serialnumber" but i insert a external device like hard disk or pan drive, this command is provide information of external hard disk or pan drive. so how can find internal hard disk information where system window installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String HDD_SerialNo(){
    StringBuffer HDD_Serial=new StringBuffer();
    String HDD_Number;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process=rt.exec(new String[]{"CMD", "/C", "WMIC diskdrive get serialnumber"});
        String s = null;
        //Reading sucessful output of the command
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            HDD_Serial.append(s);
        }
        // Reading error if any
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.print(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HDD_Number=HDD_Serial.toString();
    return HDD_Number;
}
```